# SSRS Report Data Export to CSV format for more than 1 million records

Tags: excel, t-sql, reporting-services, msbi

I am trying to export some SSRS report data to a CSV file format which has more than 1 million records but I am getting the error message below.

[image]

How can I export the more than 1 million records to an Excel CSV file from an SSRS report?

Comment: This may be obvious, but assuming this is 9 days worth of data as per your screenshot, can you halve the timeframe and try to export 4/5 days only in two tranches?

Comment: There is no row limit in SSRS, but there will be memory issue. You could try to stop other application process to see whether it works or not. In addition, you also could try to modify memory setting for report server. You could refer to Configure Available Memory for Report Server Application and System.OutOfMemoryException" error message when you use SQL Server Reporting Services for details

Comment: I faced same problem. But I export the report in multiple sheet by using row group and page breaks options. Pull the data from DB with row number and use that row number as a group of 65500 records. Because .xls file support only around 65000 rows.

Comment: I would question why are you attempting to export over a million records via SSRS to csv?  Something like that would be more suited for SSIS or bcp.